# How to add multiple values inside 1 list view and style it approriatle

Tags: java, android-layout, listview

I want to be able to add multiple values on a list but properly style the list view.

For example right now the list view will look like this:
**namepostcodedate**
which is because of the following code
`ListArray.add(jobs.get(finalJ).customer.getName() + job.getPostcode() +  job.getDate());`

[image]

The way that I am currently adding the values in the `ListArray` doesn't seem ideal but I am not sure if there is another way to do this and display the list formated?

This is my `list_item` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">
    
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/rows2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/ddOrangeLight"
            android:showDividers="middle">
<!--            android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerNameView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter class

```
public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<String>originalData = null;
    private List<String>filteredData = null;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.filteredData = data ;
        this.originalData = data ;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.uName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customerNameView);
//            holder.uPostCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postCode);
//            holder.UDateTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeView);

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
//        holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

        holder.uName.setText(filteredData.get(position));
//        holder.uPostCode.setText(filteredData.get(position));
//        holder.UDateTime.setText(filteredData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView uName;
//        TextView uPostCode;
//        TextView UDateTime;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment class

```
public class CompletedJobsFragment extends Fragment {
    AppActivity a;

    String search;
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    Vehicle vehicle;

    ListView listView;
    SearchableAdapter arrayAdapter;
    EditText searchInput;
    List<String> ListArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<ListItem> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ListItem repairDetails = new ListItem();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_completed_jobs,container,false);

        a = (AppActivity) getActivity();
        assert a != null;

        tableLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.completedJobsTable);

        Button clear = v.findViewById(R.id.btnClearTextCarReg);

        searchInput = v.findViewById(R.id.txtEditSearchCarReg);
        listView = v.findViewById(R.id.list__View);
        search = searchInput.getText().toString().trim();
        clear.setOnClickListener(av -> searchInput.setText(""));
//        Button searchButton = v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchVehicleReg);
        arrayAdapter = new SearchableAdapter(getContext(),ListArray);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setClickable(true);
        searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        JobRepository jobRepository = new JobRepository(a.getApplication());
        VehicleRepository vehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository(a.getApplication());
        jobRepository.findCompleted().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), jobs -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < jobs.size(); j++) {
                if (jobs.get(j).job == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                int finalJ = j;
                vehicleRepository.findByJob(jobs.get(j).job.getUuid()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), vehicles -> {

                    for (int vh = 0; vh < vehicles.size(); vh++) {
                        if (vehicles.get(vh).vehicle == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        vehicle = vehicles.get(vh).vehicle;
                        Job job = jobs.get(finalJ).job;

                        ListArray.add(jobs.get(finalJ).customer.getName() + job.getPostcode() +  job.getDate());

                        View viewToAdd = arrayAdapter.getView(finalJ, null, null);
                        TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[jobs.size()];
                        tableRows[finalJ] = new TableRow(a);
                        tableRows[finalJ].setId(finalJ + 1);
                        tableRows[finalJ].setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
                        tableRows[finalJ].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                        tableRows[finalJ].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_outline);
                        tableRows[finalJ].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        ));
                        tableRows[finalJ].addView(viewToAdd);

                        tableLayout.addView(tableRows[finalJ], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        ));

                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text or do whatever you need.
//                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString(JOB_ID, job.getUuid().toString());
                                bundle.putString(CUSTOMER_NAME, jobs.get(finalJ).customer.getName());
                                // bundle.putString(JOB_DATE, sdf.format(job.getDate()));

                                Fragment fragment = new ViewCustomerInformationFragment();

                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                                // Commit the transaction
                                transaction.commit();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Fragment xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBGhm"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="180dp"
        android:text="@string/completed_jobs"
        android:textColor="@color/ddGrey"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.375"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEditSearchCarReg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="12"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="22dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableTitleRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEditSearchCarReg"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGrey"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCustomerNameTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="4sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/customer_name_hc"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPostcodeTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/postcode_placeholder"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDateTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/enquiry_vat_value"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list__View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableTitleRow"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/completedJobsTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEditSearchCarReg"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClearTextCarReg"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtEditSearchCarReg"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="175dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_outline_cancel_24"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/ddOrange"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchVehicleReg"
        style="@style/DDButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEditSearchCarReg"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_outline_search_24"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.2"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/search_postcode"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```